# Nautilus not restoring opened windows but opens a new one

Tags: nautilus

I'm on 14.04

This only happens if the opened windows is showing the content of an ntfs partition - very annoying because my music and video folders are just symlinks to a common (win/ubuntu) storage hdd.

Comment: I have all symlinks to folders in an **NTFS** partition (labeled **Data**) in place of **Documents**, **Downloads**, **Music**, **Pictures**, and **Videos** in my **Home** folder. This erroneous behavior (bug?) happens only after I click one of those symlinks and the pathbar displays **Data** > **Documents** etc. But it **doesn't happen** after I right click one of those symlinks and the pathbar displays **Home** > **Documents** etc. **Maybe this should be reported to Gnome as a bug?**

Comment: I can't change the showed path to home/user/xxx, always show in the pathbar as hdd/xxx and open a new windows

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I installed nemo patched for unity as a workaround, it work perfectly as intended - and is somehow nicer than nautilus aswell -

Comment: Also considering many other bugs, like the recent background color turning to grey and then sometimes to black as well, this might be a very sensible option in deed ;-) For those interested, further info can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html and here: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-nemo-220-with-unity-patches-in.html